# How can I group and select 1 row or if there's more than 1 just the last rows with a SQL SELECT

Tags: sql-server

I have this SELECT that runs inside a SQL Server 2014 Stored Procedure.

```
SELECT   AdminTest.Title       AS Title,
         COUNT(AdminTestQuestion.AdminTestQuestionId) AS Q,
         UserTest.UserTestId AS UId,
         UserTest.TestStatusId AS Status,
         UserTest.Sequence As Sequence
FROM     AdminTest 
JOIN     UserTest
ON       AdminTest.AdminTestId = UserTest.AdminTestId 
AND      UserTest.UserId = @UserId
JOIN     AdminTestQuestion
ON       AdminTest.AdminTestId = AdminTestQuestion.AdminTestId
GROUP BY AdminTest.Title, 
         UserTest.TestStatusId, 
         UserTest.UserTestId,
         UserTest.Sequence
```

Here is the data that the select above currently returns:

```
Title    Q      UId     Status   Sequence
TestA    25     null    0        1
TestA    25     1235    2        2
TestB    10     null    0        1
TestB    10     1237    2        2
TestB    10     1238    2        3
TestC    10     null    0        1
```

Here is the data that I want to get:

```
Title    Q      UId     Status   Sequence
TestA    25     1235    2        2 
TestB    10     1237    2        2 
TestB    10     1238    2        3
TestC    10     null    0        1
```

What I am stuck on is that I need to:

- If there is only one row for a test, I need to show that row
- If there are multiple rows for a test, I need to show each row EXCEPT the first row when sorted in order of sequence number.

I know this is pretty confusing and I am thinking it's not possible to do with just a SELECT.

I would appreciate any advice on this.  If needed I could follow the SELECT with a stored procedure and use a CURSOR but I am really not sure where to start with CURSORS.

Hope someone can advise.

Comment: You are right, this is pretty confusing ;-) I don't know if I've understood this correctly... Please provide some sample data and expected output. Best was to create a [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: @Shnugo - I just updated the question to show what I have appearing so far and what I would like to get. Thanks for your feedback on the question.

Comment: @Shnugo - I tried to clarify the question even more. Can you let me know if it makes sense now? Thank you

Comment: Thx, It would help - for future questions - to state also your input data. Otherwise there is not chance to setup a test scenario... Best is, to provide  table's structure and sample data for copy'n'paste or to set up a fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comments you might try this:

The query takes all with a "Seq" higher than 1 *or* with a "Seq" of 1, but only if there is no higher "Seq":

```
;WITH MyQuery AS
(
    SELECT   AdminTest.Title       AS Title,
             COUNT(AdminTestQuestion.AdminTestQuestionId) AS Questions,
             UserTest.UserTestId AS UserTestId,
             UserTest.TestStatusId AS UserTestStatusId,
             UserTest.Sequence As Seq
    FROM     AdminTest 
    JOIN     UserTest
    ON       AdminTest.AdminTestId = UserTest.AdminTestId 
    AND      UserTest.UserId = @UserId
    JOIN     AdminTestQuestion
    ON       AdminTest.AdminTestId = AdminTestQuestion.AdminTestId
    GROUP BY AdminTest.Title, 
             UserTest.TestStatusId, 
             UserTest.UserTestId,
             UserTest.Sequence
)
SELECT *
FROM MyQuery
WHERE Seq>1
   OR (Seq=1 
       AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                      FROM MyQuery AS innerQuery 
                      WHERE innerQuery.Title=MyQuery.Title
                        AND innerQuery.Seq>1)
      );
```

Comment: Hi, can you have a look at the updates I made to the question. If there is just one row for a test then I need to see that row. If there are multiple rows for a test then I need to see all except the row with the lowest sequence number.

Comment: @Shnugo - I think it's working!  Here it is after 3am so I should finish now.  I will test it more tomorrow.  Thank you very very much.  I will update the question tomorrow.